# How to deal with Exponential errors for (minimum quantile) linear regression?

Tags: regression, exponential-distribution, quantile-regression

I have data, $(x_i, y_i)$ where $y_i$'s are responses and $x_i$'s are covariates, that appears to follow this model:

$y_i = [0.000001^\text{th} \text{ quantile linear regression of } (x_i, y_i)] + e_i$,
where $e_i \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda)$ and $\lambda$ is to be estimated.

I know how to fit the minimum, e.g. $0.000001^\text{th}$, quantile linear regression of $(x_i, y_i)$ in R using the quantreg package. So I estimated $\lambda$ by fitting an Exponential distribution for:

$$y_i - [0.000001^\text{th} \text{quantile linear regression of } (x_i, y_i)], \text{ for all } i.$$

I ended up getting $\hat{\lambda} = 4$. Then, to see if this is reasonable, I simulated $\hat{e}_i \sim Exponential(4)$ randomly for all $i$ and then computed $$\hat{y}_i = [0.000001^\text{th} \text{ quantile linear regression of } (x_i, y_i)] + \hat{e}_i$$

The plot of $(x_i, \hat{y}_i)$ looks similar to that of $(x_i, y_i)$:

[image]

**Do you have any tips on how this can be elegantly implemented? How do you estimate $\hat{y}_i$?**

Comment: You can clearly see that the linear model doesn't capture the minimum of the real data -- the envelope is distinctly curved.

Comment: You're right. It's because I didn't add in $x_i^2$ in the formula for minimum quantile regression, only $x_i$. But I think the basic idea may be the same for this model?

Comment: Yes, It's not really a problem for your question, I just wondered if you'd seen it